# Exiting position based on open profit percentage in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to code a take profit based on the currently open profit as percentage. The documentation for `strategy.openprofit` does not yield much information. It only says that the number is a float. Is this open profit the profit in the so called "base" currency? Is there a function I'm missing that would give the open profit in percent directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/mCOgJC67-Strategy/) contains `exitPercent` function. I suppose this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I had this one bookmarked. Thank you for the quick and kind help. Even if it wouldn't solve my issue, the linked library should take me pretty far.